# can i pass parameter with annotate_model rake task in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to annotate a specific model not all.

Can i pass a model name or table name with annotate_model rake task to annotate specific model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify vendor/plugins/annotate_models/lib/annotate_models.rb

replace

```
def self.do_annotations
```

with

```
def self.do_annotations(model_names=nil)
```

replace

```
model_names = model_names.split(',') unless model_names.nil?
model_names = model_names.nil? ? self.get_model_names : model_names  
model_names.each do |m|
```

with

```
self.get_model_names.each do |m|
```

Modify libs/annotate_models_tasks.rake

replace

```
AnnotateModels.do_annotations
```

with

```
AnnotateModels.do_annotations ENV['MODEL_NAMES']
```

Now you can pass parameter to the rake task..

Example:

```
 rake annotate_models MODEL_NAMES=csv_header,csv_columne
```

pass filenames without .rb in parameter.

May be that will help ...